# What are the ideals in ${\Bbb C}[x,y]$ that contain $f_1,f_2\in{\Bbb C}[x,y]$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

This question is based on an exercise in Artin's *Algebra*:

> Which ideals in the polynomial ring $R:={\Bbb C}[x,y]$ contain $f_1=x^2+y^2-5$ and $f_2=xy-2$?

Using Hilbert's (weak) nullstellensatz, one can identify all the *maximal* ideals of $R$ that contain $f_1$ and $f_2$. For the general ideals contain $(f_1, f_2)$, it suffices to identify ideals in $R/(f_1,f_2)$ by the correspondence theorem. But I don't see how to go on. Is there a systematic way to do it?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this counts as a "systematic" way of doing it or not, but you can do the following.

First, in the ring $R$ you have $y = 2/x$, so you have the isomorphism $$R = \frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{(f_1,f_2)}\cong \frac{\mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}]}{(x^2 + 4x^{-2} - 5)}.$$ Observe that you have the factorization of ideals $$x^2 + 4x^{-2} - 5 = (x-2)(x+2)(x-1)(x+1)$$ in the ring $\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}]}{(x^2 + 4x^{-2} - 5)}$. These are pairwise coprime maximal ideals, so the Chinese remainder theorem says that $$\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}]}{(x^2 + 4x^{-2} - 5)}\cong \frac{\mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}]}{(x-2)}\times \frac{\mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}]}{(x+2)}\times \frac{\mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}]}{(x-1)}\times \frac{\mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}]}{(x+1)}$$$$\cong \mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}.$$ Unraveling definitions, we see that $R\cong \mathbb{C}^4$, the isomorphism being $$f(x,y)\mapsto (f(2,1), f(-2, -1), f(1,2), f(-1,-2)).$$

Now, to understand what the ideals of $R$ are, you need to know what the ideals of $\mathbb{C}^4$ are. There are $2^4$ ideals of $\mathbb{C}^4$, corresponding to subsets $S\subseteq\{1,2,3,4\}$; namely, the ideals $$I_S = \{(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) : a_i = 0\,\,\,\mathrm{ if }\,\,\,i\in S\}.$$ There are therefore $2^4$ ideals of $R$, corresponding to subsets $S\subseteq\{1,2,3,4\}$; namely the ideals $$J_S = \{f : (f(2,1), f(-2,-1), f(1,2), f(-1,-2))\in I_S\}.$$ I hope this analysis works!

Comment: In your factorization in the 5th line, I think there is a factor $x^{-2}$?

Comment: @Jack: You are correct, but remember this is a factorization of ideals, and $x^{-1}$ is a unit in $\mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}]$, so the extra factor of $x^{-2}$ does not matter here....

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't know much about the ideal factorization. It seems the answer depends mainly on the special forms of $f_1$ and $f_2$. Can it be generalized to any $f_1, f_2$?

Comment: @Jack: Yeah, one of the nice things about these equations is that we are easily able to eliminate the $y$-variable by writing it as $y = 2/x$. Once we do this, we get an equation depending only on $x$, and then because $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed you can always factor a polynomial in one variable. As for any $f_1,f_2$, I think you would have to be more careful if you can't solve for $y$ that easily....

Comment: froggie, is your $R$ a different $R$ from the OP?

Comment: froggie, why isn't $$f(x,y)\mapsto (f(2,1), f(-2, -1), f(1,2), f(-1,-2))$$ a homomorphism instead? I think the isomorphism is $$[f(x,y) + (x^2+4x^{-2}-5)]\mapsto (f(2,1), f(-2, -1), f(1,2), f(-1,-2))$$

Comment: froggie, did you mean $\subseteq I_S$ instead of $\in I_S$?

Comment: @JackBauer Obviously in this answer $R=\mathbb C[X,Y]/(f_1,f_2)$. No need to ask this, really!

Comment: The second question seems also unnecessary. The answer to third question is NO.

Comment: @user26857 $I_S$ is a set of ideals instead of an ideal depending on the set $S$?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a procedure that works more generally: the ideal $I := (x^2 + y^2 - 5, xy - 2)$ has height $2$ in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. To see this, note that $x^2 + y^2 - 5$ (or $xy - 2$) is irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$ (e.g. by Eisenstein), hence generates a height $1$ prime ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, which does not contain the other generator. More generally yet, the generators of $I$ form a [regular sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_sequence), and any ideal generated by a regular sequence has height equal to the length of the sequence.

Thus, the quotient $R := \mathbb{C}[x,y]/I$ has Krull dimension $\le \dim \mathbb{C}[x,y] - \text{ht}(I) = 0$, so $R$ is an Artinian ring. Every Artinian ring is a finite product of Artinian local rings, and ideals in a finite product are products of ideals, so writing $R = \prod_{i=1}^n R_i$, the number of $R$-ideals is the product of the numbers of $R_i$-ideals.

In this particular case, $R = R_1 \times \cdots \times R_4$, each $R_i \cong \mathbb{C}$ by the Nullstellensatz, and $\mathbb{C}$ has precisely $2$ ideals, so $R$ has a total of $2^4 = 16$ ideals.